# Noisy fan on ASRock 330

Tags: fan

The cpu fan on my ASRock 330 has been making really horrible noises, and it's so close to the other heatsink (On some other component) that I can't remove it and fix it.

I googled a bit and found this page: http://asrockion.wiki.zoho.com/silencing-the-ASRock-ION330.html and this image:
[image]

Which looks similar to mine, but in mine the fan and the heatsink opposite it are even closer, almost touching.

So, I'm thinking about just unplugging the fan, but I'm not sure if that is a good idea?

I'm not that experienced with hardware, if I just unplug it and it overheats, will it just turn off?

Also any other solutions on how to remove it, fix it, etc is appreciated.

Comment: *Don’t* just unplug the fan. Simply unplugging it would mean that the side the fan is on is practically blocked, preventing air from escaping which would almost certainly create heat problems. If you must stop the fan, then remove it altogether; at least that way, you leave the side free, allowing air to move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against removing/disabling the fan... especially in such a small & compact setup.  Instead, I would look at pulling the fan & heat-sink assembly out... cleaning it all up/replacing fan if necessary.  Also, add a dab of thermal-paste between the heat-sink & chip to ensure good heat transfer.

If yours is indeed similar to that picture... you'll notice the little white plastic clips that are spring loaded on either side of the heat-sink.  You should be able to pop them up... and then the heat-sink & fan should come right out.

Comment: Oh, I didn't dare to tinker with those clips, because I didn't know what they were. Thanks!

Comment: Even if you do not remove the heatsink, at least remove the fan and clean and oil it. (Though you will probably have to remove the block heatsink on opposite the fan—there are black, spring-loaded tabs holding it to the motherboard—look on the underside of the mobo to remove them—but at that point, you may as well just remove the heatsink the fan is attached to instead.)